# Проверка существования id пользователя перед добавлением нового

Tags: python, бот

Как проверить есть ли id юзера в базе чтобы он не записывал повторно? Т.е. если есть, то не записываем, если нет, то вносим данные. Код работает, но осталось только написать проверку. Полагаю, что

> cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM stats WHERE userid = ?", (userid))
>
> result = cursor.fetchone()

но нужно еще дописать и куда поставить чтобы проверял. Надеюсь, что понятно объяснил (я учусь). Вот весь код:

```
import telebot
import const
import time
import random
from keyboards import *
import sqlite3

bot = telebot.TeleBot(const.token)

conn = sqlite3.connect("mybase.db")
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS stats (id INT, username VARCHAR, name VARCHAR, surname VARCHAR)")
conn.commit()
conn.close()

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start(message):
    userid = message.from_user.id
    username = message.from_user.username
    user_name = message.from_user.first_name
    user_surname = message.from_user.last_name
    conn = sqlite3.connect("mybase.db")
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO stats VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)", (userid, username, user_name, user_surname))
    conn.commit()
    my_id = 410924655
    if userid == my_id:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Привет, Хозяин!', reply_markup=menu)
        time.sleep(1)
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Выбери нужный пункт:', reply_markup=admenu)
    else:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Привет, ' + message.from_user.first_name + '!', reply_markup=menu)
        time.sleep(1)
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Нажми кнопку "Задать вопрос" и произнеси вопрос.\nШар ответит тебе через 5 секунд.', reply_markup=quest)
    conn.close()

@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def message(message):
    if message.text == 'Реклама в боте':
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Чтобы ознакомиться с прайсом и заказать рекламу напишите нам  @мой акк', reply_markup=quest)
    elif message.text == 'Тех. поддержка':
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Если у вас есть какой-то вопрос, пожелания и предложения, то напишите нам  @мой акк', reply_markup=quest)
    else:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, message.from_user.first_name + ', я всего лишь бот. Может быть у тебя есть какой-то вопрос?', reply_markup=quest)

@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
def ques(call):
    if call.data == 'quest1':
        bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, 'Произнесите вопрос')
        o = random.choice(const.otvet)
        time.sleep(5)
        bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, o)
        time.sleep(1)
        bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, 'Может быть у вас есть еще вопрос?', reply_markup=quest)
    elif call.data == 'stat':
        conn = sqlite3.connect("mybase.db")
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        cursor.execute("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM stats")
        r = cursor.fetchall()
        bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, f'Всего пользователей: {r[0][0]}')
        conn.close()

if __name__ == 'main':
    print('Bot has been started...')
bot.polling(none_stop=True, interval=0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Во-первых, сделать `id` первичным ключом. Во-вторых, `INSERT OR IGNORE INTO stats VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)`.

Comment: Тогда, мб и добавить пример -- `id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY`? :)

Comment: зачем мне primary key? Как я понял это порядковый номер, а мне нужны id пользователей. Общее количество я получаю "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM stats"

Comment: @ЮрийПопов чтобы `OR IGNORE` работало и можно было не делать лишних запросов к базе, тем более таких медленных, как `COUNT`. Впрочем можно обойтись и просто ограничением уникальности на поле `id`.